# Returning different values based on where function is called from in Python

Tags: python

I have two functions, each of which call a third function, but expect a slightly different thing returned back.

All functions are in separate files. Files A and B can NOT import one another, so function A and B can not call one another. What is the best way to organize this?

I would like to avoid duplicating the function, since most of it is identical, to stay in line with DRY principals.

Here is some pseudo-code for what I have, and how I am thinking the program would be structured:

```
#FileA.py
def functionA():
    useableData = functionC(rawData)
```

-

```
#FileB.py
def functionB():
    useableData = functionC(rawData)
```

-

```
#FileC.py
def functionC(rawdata):
    *Extensive processing/formatting of data*
    if C run from A:
        return useableData

    if C run from B:
        *A bit more processing of data*
        return useableData
```

The only solution I can think of is to pass a second variable along with `rawdata`, a string that says the name of the function it came from. But this seems inelegant to me.

Is there an ideal way to do this? Perhaps not involving checking where the function was called from, but still allowing `functionC` to return slightly different results depending on where the data is going to be returned to. I might be able to restructure the code a bit, but all three functions need to remain in their current files.

Comment: While I think this is a horrible idea, there is always the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module. It's bad form though to change behavior based on the caller, without any additional context information. It's not bad form to add an additional argument specifying what _type_ of processing is to be performed, though

Comment: Just add an (optional) second parameter `moreProcessing=False`?

Comment: I would recommend putting anything that is specific to what fileA needs into functionA and anything specific to fileB in functionB and leaving functionC to only handle what is common to both.

Comment: I've noticed that almost any time I've wanted to get something similar but different back from a function, I usually want a different function. Maybe I need to make two new functions and extract the uncommon behavior into those new functions... but I predict pain in your future. (Cake is awesome, though)

Comment: You could have `functionA` and `functionB` set the value of a module-level global that `functionC` checks when called. The only scenario in which that would be preferable to just passing an additional argument to `functionC` is if for some reason you can change the implementation of the three functions, but not the signature of `functionC`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. The situation is a bit more complicated than I indicate here, but I'm thinking passing a "moreProcessing=False/True" will work out fine. Will get back when I have it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just add an extra function argument?

```
def functionC(rawdata, extra_processing=False):
    # extensive processing
    if extra_processing:
        # more processing
    return usable_data
```

Then in A you call it as `functionC(stuff)`, and in B you call `functionC(stuff, extra_processing=True)`

Answer (score 3):

I think your approach is wrong. What I would do is this

```
def functionA():
    useabledata = functionC(rawData)


def functionB():
    useabledata = functionD(functionC(rawData))


def functionC(rawData):
   *Extensive processing/formatting of data*

def functionD(partiallyProcessedData):
   *A bit more processing of data*
```

Other option is as tobias_k said, to have an optional second parameter

```
def functionC(rawData, moreProcessing=False):
    *Extensive processing*
    if not moreProcessing:
        return data
    *more processing*
    return data
```

And call it like

```
def functionA()
    useabledata = functionC(rawData)

def functionB()
    useabledata = functionC(rawData, True)
```

An even more encapsulated way to do it would be

```
def functionA():
    useabledata = functionC(rawData)


def functionB():
    useabledata = functionD(rawData)


def functionC(rawData):
   *Extensive processing/formatting of data*

def functionD(rawData):
   partialProcessedData = functionC(rawData)
   *A bit more processing of data*
```

Comment: Those are both good ways to organize it. I'll need to give some though to exactly how I want to do it, but thanks!